# How to setup a package to my laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-blade

I am really new to Laravel so I am sorry for my incompetence in understanding. Hope someone can help me out.

Basically I am trying to install this package https://github.com/musonza/chat/ into my Laravel project that uses Jetstream with Livewire. Now I have gone through the setup process but the part where I am confused is that the below code should be in it's own model?:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Musonza\Chat\Traits\Messageable;

class Bot extends Model
{
    use Messageable;
}
```

If yes then would the following code that is used to create a conversation go in a blade file aka the frontend? If not then where should this code go?:

```
$participants = [$model1, $model2,..., $modelN];

$conversation = Chat::createConversation($participants);
```

If you also check the page that I have linked there is a code to retrieve a conversation and sending a message. If anything can please just give me a basic rundown as to how am I supposed to like put the create conversation code and retrieve conversation code in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

i´ll try to answer all questions, as far as i get your right.
so first of all, you have to insert

```
use Musonza\Chat\Traits\Messageable;
...
use Messageable;
```

in every model, which will participate, e.g. Models of "Customers", "Merchants", etc.

The `$participants`-array just contains all the models from the participating usergroups like in my example.

The `$conversation`-array is the key: this array will return / contains a conversation processed by the `createConversation` function.

To answer your question: `$conversation` must be passed to blade to display a conversation in the UI. The Snippet can go anywhere, as long as you inject the class `Chat` in the php-file, e.g. your Livewire-File.

Livewire makes it easy to pass data to the UI.
Lets say you have a Livewire Class "Customers", here you you have inject the Chat class, like so:

```
use Chat;
```

Each Livewire class has a render method (you could also use the mount method), where you can place your variables to get the data.

```
public function render()
    {
        $this->conversation = Chat::createConversation($participants);
        return view('livewire.chat.layout'); //example
    }
```

It´s madatory to make variables (properties) in Livewire public, to pass them to the frontend.
In your case, it could be like:

```
public $conversation
```

and in the render-method you can simply assign `$this->conversation` any value.

In the frontend (blade-file, e.g. `chat.layout.blade.php`) now, simply write {{ $conversation }} to print.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply back to me. I just had one more question, so let's say I create a blade file that has a form and when you submit that form I want it to create a conversation and redirect the user to that conversation, so how would I go about in doing that?